# VStack messes with task modifier?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, async-await

I'm creating a view called `AsyncDataView`. The idea is, whenever the view appears, it will start an asynchronous `Task` to download data from wherever. While its in the process of downloading, the view should display a `ProgressView`.

Once the `Task` is complete and the data has been downloaded, the view should display the downloaded data in a `Text` view.

I thought this would be a fairly easy implementation, here's a minimal example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = 0..<100
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self) { _ in
                // Removing the VStack resolves the issue!
                VStack {
                    AsyncDataView()
                }
            }
            
            Text("Middle Panel")
        }
    }
}

struct AsyncDataView: View {
    @State private var data: String?
    
    @ViewBuilder private var mainBody: some View {
        if let data = data {
            Text(data)
        }
        else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        mainBody
            .task {
                // Simulate loading data from a website or whatever
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                
                // @State is thread safe according to Apple docs
                data = String(Int.random(in: 0..<100))
            }
    }
}
```

Here, I just have a `List` of 100 of these `AsyncDataView`'s. Whenever an `AsyncDataView` appears, a `Task` is started. The `Task` just sleeps 1 second to simulate downloading, and then assigns data.

**Problem**:
Whenever I scroll down the `List` really quickly, and then scroll back up, some items **never** finish loading. They just remain with the spinning `ProgressView`.

It's best displayed with a video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWumv.jpg

Or a GIF for convenience:
[image]

In the video, I wait for the initial items to be loaded. I then scroll down, and then back up. At the end, you can see 4 items which never loaded.

**The kicker**: The weirdest thing is that if I remove the `VStack` inside the body of the `List` then this issue resolves! It appears the `VStack` messes with the `task` modifier! Or, what I've also seen, is maybe the `VStack` resets the `@State` inside of the `AsyncDataView` for some reason?

I would just remove the currently redundant `VStack`, but the issue is in my actual use-case I need to have another view displayed below this one.

**Is anybody able to reproduce this, and does anybody know what's up with this code? Or is this a SwiftUI bug, as @Asperi suggested?**

This was done on `macOS Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258)`.

Comment: Looks like a List bug on macOS, use instead ScrollView + LazyVStack.

Comment: @Asperi Shoot. Unfortunately, I can't really use a ScrollView + LazyVStack because I need the List selection capabilities and standard styling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be platform dependent.

A possible approach is to move async fetching data logic into view model and leave view update just on main actor.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var data: String?

        init() {
            update()
        }

        func update() {
            Task.detached {
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)

                await MainActor.run {
                    self.data = String(Int.random(in: 0..<100))
                }
            }
        }
    }

// ...

@StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    if let data = vm.data {
        Text(data)
    }
    else {
        ProgressView()
    }
}
```

[Complete findings and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/Async_data_task_inList.md)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However it doesn't seem to work (the result is still the same). My question was for macOS, not iOS though. Could that be the reason?

Comment: See update with found solution

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Unfortunately, I don't think I can use this, because by downloading the data when the StateObject is initialized, then it causes every item in a list to be loaded immediately. For example, if I have 100,000 items, then **all** of those will be downloaded. However, with onAppear, this doesn't happen. It incrementally loads them

Comment: I found a really weird workaround to this issue though. By adding a `ViewModifier` which applies an empty `contextMenu`, and then using that on the `VStack`, then this issue is completely solved